# Inter-App Communication Issue: Unexpected Behavior in Android App Interaction and Remote Logging Challenges

Tags: android, android-intent

I've developed an Android app that has a feature where it communicates with another app using Intents. Essentially, my app sends data to the other app, which processes it and sends the result back. Here's how the activity flow works:

My app's home activity -> My app's launch activity <-> Other app (which processes and returns the result back to launch activity)

When I test this feature, it works perfectly. However, my customer has reported an issue: sometimes, they're redirected to my app's home screen instead of the launch screen after the processing is completed in the other app. when this happens, my app's launch screen doesn't receive the result via the OnActivityResult method.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to monitor the logcat in my customers' environments due to certain limitations. Although I've enabled Firebase Crashlytics, it hasn't reported any errors. Do you have any insights into what might be causing this issue? Additionally, is there a way to remotely access the full Android system log, including the logcat without app filters?

Comment: `Inter-App Communication Issue` Big words. Your problem is only with startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult(). Not even mentioned in the flow scheme.

Comment: `Essentially, my app sends data to the other app` I think that your app starts the other app first.